# C++ Bool functions

Tags: c++

I have a bit of a problem with `bool` functions. The second sentence prints out no matter the salary I would input. I'm new to programming.

My task:

> Define a function that will decide if someone can rent an apartment based on the salary he/she makes.
>
> The rent should be at most one-third of the salary. If it is more than one third, the customer’s application will be denied.
>
> The function’s purpose is to decide whether the customer is qualified or not.

Here is my problem child:

```
if (age > 17)
{               
    if (canbuy(salary, rent))
    {
        cout << "Based on the information you have provided, you are qualified. You are old enough and have money." << endl << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Based on the information you have provided, you are not qualified. Sorry... Make more money next time.  " << endl << endl;
    }
}
```

Here is the function definition for 'canbuy':

```
bool canbuy(double salary, double rent)
{
    if (rent <= ((1 / 3)* salary))
    {
        return true;
    }    
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

    return canbuy;
}
```

Visual example of outcome:
[https://i.imgur.com/WE28e1H.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWyOV.png)

Here is the whole program:

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Define a function that will decide if someone can rent an apartment based on the salary he/she makes.

//The rent should be at most one-third of the salary. If it is more than one third, the customer’s application will be denied.  

bool canbuy(double salary, double rent);

const double rent = 1200;
    
int main()
{
    int salary;
    int age;
    char ans;
    string fullname, lastname;

    do
    {
        cout << "Hello. Welcome to the Renting Evolution Center... " << endl << endl;

        cout << "This apartment's monthly rent is $1200. " << endl << endl;

        cout << "I need to gather your information to see if you qualify: " << endl << endl;

        cout << "Your full name, please:     ";

        cin >> fullname;
        cin >> lastname;
        cout << endl;
        
        cout << "Your age, please:   ";
        cin >> age;
        cout << endl;
            
        cout << "Your salary, please:     ";
        cin >> salary;
        cout << endl;

        cout << "We will now process your information to see if you are qualified to purchase a house..." << endl << endl;

        system("pause");
            
        if (age > 17)
        {               
            if (canbuy(salary, rent))
            {
                cout << "Based on the information you have provided, you are qualified. You are old enough and have money." << endl << endl;
                
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Based on the information you have provided, you are not qualified. Sorry... Make more money next time.  " << endl << endl;                 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Based on the information you have provided, you are not qualified. Sorry... Get older next time..." << endl << endl;
        }
            
        cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" << endl;
        cout << "Would you like to enter new information?: ";
        cin >> ans;
        cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" << endl;

        cout << endl;

    } while (ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y');

    cout << "Goodluck with house shopping! " << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

bool canbuy(double salary, double rent)
{
    if (rent <= ((1 / 3)* salary))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

    return canbuy;
}
```

Comment: `rent <= ((1 / 3)* salary)` the rhs will always be `0` as `(1/3)` evaluates to `0`. `1` and `3` are `ints` and hence the result will be `int` as well. Change this to `rent <= ((1.0 / 3)* salary)'`

Comment: Drop the `return canbuy;` statement from your `canbuy()` function. It's never reached, and if it were it would be just about meaningless. (It implicitly converts the value of `canbuy`, treated as a function *pointer* to `bool`, which always yields `true` since it's a non-null pointer). This isn't the cause of your problem, just a bit of cleanup of useless code.

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing with the program, and you have a logic error within your `canbuy` function.

As Saliesh D stated earlier in the comments, within the line `if rent( <= ((1/3) * salary))` the 1 and the 3 are treated as integers.  Therefore, it will truncate your decimal result and round to the lowest integer.  In your case 1/3 will evaluate to 0.

In a test case I had two integers, `a = 1` and `b = 3`.  When `a / b`, the resulting output results to `0`.

To solve this, you can specify the numbers to be floating point by just doing

`if (rent <= ((1.0/3.0) * salary))`

Comment: Also, as mentioned before you have to drop the `return canbuy;` statement as this does not the thing you think it does! Also, this statement is never reached as the function returns always before this statement.